# What's a word or a phrase for "going down the stairs quickly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was thinking of "to storm out of a room" and I'm wondering if there's an equivalent word (**edit:** or phrase) that means to go down flights of stairs at a rapid pace. Maybe "bounced down the stairs"?

Comment: Are you really looking for a single word, or are you looking for a phrase? Do you have any context beyond what you have given?

Comment: Depends on the image you want to convey.  "Bounced" suggests a "lively" stride.  "Clomped" suggests a more pounding stride (and possibly not as fast).  Or you can simply say "sped".  (Note that "stormed out of the room" suggests anger.)

Comment: If you skip over steps, it might be "bounded", although that also seems to suggest going up rather than down.

Comment: Ran down the steps or flew down the steps/stairs. Careened.  Rachetted.

Comment: @Xanne he wants a word for it. Not a substitute for X in **X down the stairs**. That'd be too easy.

Comment: @vickyace He himself suggests "bounced down the stairs."  And yes, it was easy.

Comment: This confusion about what the asker wants is why word and phrase requests always need a clearly stated sample sentence included, which shows exactly where the word (or phrase) would be used in the sentence.

Comment: “He bounced down the stairs” sounds to me like he tripped over something at the top and can expect to be quite severely bruised and damaged when he reaches the bottom… so I wouldn’t use that.

Comment: @Xanne You're right.  Well,  he should just have googled it then.  Common resources.

Comment: @vickyace - except that it's not always easy knowing where to look.  And even if you do, how do you choose between the options.  Of the ones on offer I like 'careened' best - not a word that quickly came to my mind.  If Xanne made a case for it, it would get my vote.

Comment: I didn't realize that phrase-requests was a valid tag. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ***fly*** and ***race*** are often used for this meaning - [he ***flew*** down the stairs; she ***raced*** down the stairs.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flew+down+the+stairs%2C+raced+down+the+stairs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflew%20down%20the%20stairs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craced%20down%20the%20stairs%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The question asks for a word, this is a phrase.

Comment: @vickyace - the OP template is *"to storm out of a room"*.  The operative word is '*storm*'.  You cannot say "*He stormed*" and expect "*out of the room*" to be understood.  My suggestions work in the same way.

Comment: Well then, I'll sure retract my vote, but then this question can be solved with common resources.

Answer (score 3):

He *careened* down the stairs.

careen, v. (Cambridge Dictionary)

> to go forward, esp. quickly, while moving from side to side: The car
>   skidded and careened wildly across several lanes of traffic.

richochet, v. is a possibility also; I had thought this gave a side-to-side idea, perhaps hitting opposite walls as he went down, but it seems to apply mainly to small objects:

> (of a ball, bullet, or other small object) to bounce off a surface:
>   The ball ricocheted off the goalie’s foot and into the net.

Comment: I thought that was "careered" down the road (and Careen 'to strip the barnacles off a boat); but N-grams shows **careered downhill** (much more frequent) Br English/ and **careened downhill** Am. Eng. I like "ricochet,"  a strong audio-visual metaphor for someone clattering down stairs. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

They might be *galloping* down the stairs. This is evocative of the cadence, sound and speed of the foot-falls.

See the example given in the following dictionary entry:

> **gallop** *verb*
>   3 to move very quickly (SYN run)
>   *Ian came galloping down the stairs*.
>   [- Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/gallop)

(Note that the single word *gallop* on its own has nothing to do with stairs.)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to be really rapid, there's always ***tumbled*** down the stairs... but that doesn't really suggest that the feet are what's making contact with the stairs.